# When is it safe to call native_handle() on a std::thread?

Tags: linux, c++11, pthreads

I am creating a `std::thread` and then subsequently attempting to get the native handle (which will be used to set the thread name).

```
auto mThread = std::thread(threadActionFcn);

#ifdef DEFINITELY_LINUX_PTHREADS
auto handle = mThread.native_handle();
pthread_setname_np(handle, name);
#endif
```

Can I guarantee that `mThread` is initialised after the constructor has executed or is this a race condition?

Answer (score 0):

You can make any call you want on the std::thread object aber it has been created, of course. Everything else would be a huge pitfall.